# Change directory listing language lighttpd

Tags: localization, lighttpd

I've enabled lighttpd 1.4.32 in my NAS in order to serve couple of documents with some friends. I've changed the css to make it friendlier and I now want to change the language of the labels to Spanish, I mean:

```
Index of = Índice de
Name = Nombre
Last modified = Última modificación
```

and so on

With Apache I knew I changed that somehow, but I'm unable to find the right line to add to lighttpd.conf

Thanks in advance and sorry for my poor English

Enrique

Answer (score 0):

You might try writing some custom javascript and putting it in the readme file.  See `dir-listing.show-readme` and `dir-listing.encode-readme` at https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModDirlisting